# Add zeros to data matrix based on length of other matrix keeping colname order

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

I have the below matrix `mat1`:

```
mat1 <- matrix (1:16, 4)
colnames(mat1) <- c("A1","B2","C3","D4"); row.names(mat1) <- c("A1","B2","C3","D4")

 mat1
   A1 B2 C3 D4
A1  1  5  9 13
B2  2  6 10 14
C3  3  7 11 15
D4  4  8 12 16
```

I also have a smaller matrix `small_mat`:

```
small_mat <- matrix (1:4, 2)
colnames(small_mat) <- c("A1","C3"); row.names(small_mat) <- c("A1","C3")

  A1 C3
A1  1  3
C3  2  4
```

I want to make `small_mat` the same size as `mat1`, adding zeros where needed and keeping `colnames` and `row.names` in the same order as `mat1`.

**Desired result:**

```
       A1 B2 C3 D4
    A1  1  0  3  0
    B2  0  0  0  0
    C3  2  0  4  0
    D4  0  0  0  0
```

I've tried making a matrix of zeros from missing `small_mat` `colnames` and subsequently using `rbind.fill.matrix` but not getting quite there:

```
not_in_small_mat <- colnames(mat1)[!(colnames(mat1) %in% colnames(small_mat))] # see what colnames are missing from small_mat 
zeros <- matrix(data=0,nrow=length(not_in_small_mat),ncol=length(colnames(mat1))) # create matrix of those needing adding 
colnames(zeros) <- colnames(mat1)

result <- rbind.fill.matrix(small_mat,zeros)

    A1 C3 B2 D4
[1,]  1  3 NA NA
[2,]  2  4 NA NA
[3,]  0  0  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will insert the `small_mat` into a zero'd matrix

```
mat1 <- matrix(rep(0, 16), 4)
colnames(mat1) <- c("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4")
row.names(mat1) <- c("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4")

small_mat <- matrix(1:4, 2)
colnames(small_mat) <- c("A1", "C3")
row.names(small_mat) <- c("A1", "C3")

mat1[rownames(small_mat), colnames(small_mat)] <- small_mat

mat1
   A1 B2 C3 D4
A1  1  0  3  0
B2  0  0  0  0
C3  2  0  4  0
D4  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Worth mentioning that the `dimnames` of `mat1` need to be there - I neglected this in my real data, wasting half an hour!